# Finding a Z for which we can show that i/-i is a branch point

Tags: complex-analysis, branch-points

I have been given the following formula:
$$
f(z) = \sqrt{(z^2+1)} = \sqrt{(z+i)(z-i)}
$$

And I have to prove that i and -i are two branch points: if you make a circle around either of those points in the domain you do not end up in the same spot as where you started.

So I try to do that and the first step for me would be to find a z for which this goes. The easy one seems to be 
$$
z = e^{xi} + i
$$
But this does not work: $f(e^{0i} + i) = f(e^{2 \pi i} + i) = \sqrt{(1+2i)} = \sqrt{(1+2i)(1)}$

Is my Z function wrong, am I missing something? Which Z function will show me that $z = z_1$ does not lead to $f(z) = f(z_1)$ when going around i and -i?

Comment: I think you mean $\sqrt{z^2+1}$.

Comment: Yeah, you are right.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure either, but I believe it has something to do with the was the square root function is defined in the complex plane. Typically it is defined as

$$
\sqrt(z)=e^{\frac 12\log(z)},
$$
where $\log$ is some branch of the logarithm. If we choose the principle branch and look at a circle of radius 1 centered at $z=0$,
$$
\sqrt(e^{0i})=e^{\frac 12(1+0i)}=e^{\ln 1/2}=\frac 1 2
$$
(accidentally pressed enter... one moment)

Comment: I'm not entirely sure either, but I believe it has something to do with the way the square root function is defined in the complex plane. Typically it is defined as

$$
\sqrt{z}=e^{\frac 12\log(z)},
$$
where $\log$ is some branch of the logarithm. Recall that $\log(z)=\ln|z|+\text{Arg}(z)i$. If we choose the principle branch and look at a circle of radius 1 centered at $z=0$,
$$
\sqrt{e^{0i}}=e^{\frac 12(\ln 1+0i)}=e^0=1
$$
but
$$
\sqrt{e^{2\pi i}}=e^{\frac 12 (\ln 1+2\pi)}=e^{\pi i}=-1,
$$
since $\ln 1=0$. Sorry about the previous comment, I'm relatively new to the website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Funny thing: the answer is in my question, but I made a mistake while calculating. First, $f(z)$:
$$
f(z) = \sqrt{(z^2+1)} = \sqrt{(z+i)(z-i)} = \sqrt{z+i}\sqrt{z-i}
$$
Then: $e^{xi} + i$, so lets compare $z_1 = e^{0i} + i$ and $z_2 = e^{(0 + 2\pi)i} + i = e^{0i}e^{2\pi i} + i$ 
$$
f(e^{0i} + i) = (\sqrt{e^{0i} + 2i})e^{\frac{0}{2}i} = \sqrt{1 + 2i}
$$
$$
f(e^{0i}e^{2\pi i} + i) = (\sqrt{e^{0i}e^{2\pi i} + 2i})e^{\frac{0}{2}i}e^{\pi i} = -\sqrt{1 + 2i}
$$

Hence, branch point at $z = i$. Same thing goes for $z = -i$